# How do add headers to Next.js JSON response?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

This is how you respond with JSON:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export const GET = async () => {
  return NextResponse.json({
    status: 'OK',
  });
};
```

This is how you add headers:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export const GET = async () => {
  const response = NextResponse.next();

  response.headers.set('X-Robots-Tag', 'noindex');

  // ...
};
```

How do I combine them?

I tried `response.json({})` but that is not it.

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out:

```
export const GET = async () => {
  const response = NextResponse.json({
    status: 'OK',
  });

  response.headers.set('X-Robots-Tag', 'noindex');

  return response;
};
```